# Convert X days to Y M D

Tags: php, strtotime

At the moment, Im using this code below to calculate the amount of days my website has been running for. It works great, but I would like it to return the amount of days in Y M D days.

For Example, we have been hosting for X years, X months and X days.

Heres what i have

```
    <?


    $startTimeStamp = strtotime("2013/06/18");
    $endTimeStamp = date('Y-m-d');

    $timeDiff = abs($endTimeStamp - $startTimeStamp);

    $numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day



    // and you might want to convert to integer
    $numberDays = intval($numberDays);  ?>

    Hosting for <? echo $numberDays; ?> days!
```

I think i need to use mktime for this, but i am not to sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Use OOP `DateTime` :)

Comment: `$endTimeStamp = time();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with [`DateTime::diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) and [`DateInterval::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php):

```
$start = new DateTime('2013/06/18');
$now = new DateTime();

$interval = $now->diff($start);
echo $interval->format('%y year(s), %m month(s), %d day(s)');

// 1 year(s), 1 month(s), 22 day(s)
```